# Trying to output ➜ on powershell prompt with cmder

Tags: powershell, command-line, cmder

I am using `cmder` console with `powershell` and creating a custom prompt.  So I creae a task that looks like this:

```
*PowerShell -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -NoLogo -NoExit -new_console:d:"%USERPROFILE%"
```

Now inside `Microsoft.PowerShell_profile.ps1` I create a prompt that looks like:

```
[Console]::OutputEncoding = [System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8

function prompt
{
    Write-Host "➜"  -nonewline -foregroundcolor Magenta 
}
```

Now the prompt outputs:

```
âžœPS>
```

So my `➜` is not outputting correct.  So I copy

```
âžœPS>function prompt { Write-Host "➜"  -nonewline -foregroundcolor Magenta }
```

and paste it right into `cmder` prompt and now the prompt outputs

```
➜PS>
```

as it should.  How can I get `cmder` to output `UTF8` at the command prompt when putting it in `Microsoft.PowerShell_profile.ps1`?

Comment: Is your `Microsoft.PowerShell_profile.ps1` saved in UTF8 (and does that matter?)

Comment: According to `VSCode` it is saved in `UTF8`.

Comment: UTF-8 with BOM or without BOM?

Comment: Its without `BOM`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37235562

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on @PetSerAl responses I did need to save the file as `UTF8 with BOM`.

I am also able to remove `Console]::OutputEncoding = [System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8` from my `Microsoft.PowerShell_profile.ps1`. 
  Now my `Microsoft.PowerShell_profile.ps1` looks like:

```
function prompt
{
    Write-Host "➜"  -nonewline -foregroundcolor Magenta 
}
```