# Powershell ps1 file fails but code is good

Tags: powershell

When I run my Powershell script from the command line, it fails, however if I copy line by line and run it in Powershell Console it runs fine.

```
powershell -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File "F:\email.ps1" -FFFeatureOff
```

yields:

> At F:\email.ps1:16 char:126
>   + ... ential("username", "password");
>   +                                                                       ~~~ The string is missing the terminator: ".
>
> At F:\email.ps1:9 char:1
>   + {
>   + ~ Missing closing '}' in statement block or type definition.

Its just really odd if I open powershell window and paste the script in, it works, but running the ps1 file I get the error, even in the editor I get the same issues

Full Script:

```
$EmailTo = "xxxxx"
$EmailFrom = "xxxxxx"
$Subject = "LicenceKey & Instructions"
$Body = "This is an automated email"
$SMTPServer = "smtp.gmail.com"
$SMTPMessage = New-Object System.Net.Mail.MailMessage($EmailFrom,$EmailTo,$Subject,$Body)
$files=Get-ChildItem "C:\Users\alber\Desktop\LicenceKey\newuser"
Foreach($file in $files)
{
    Write-Host “Attaching File :- ” $file
    $attachment = New-Object System.Net.Mail.Attachment –ArgumentList "C:\Users\alber\Desktop\LicenceKey\newuser\$file"
    $SMTPMessage.Attachments.Add($attachment)
}
$SMTPClient = New-Object Net.Mail.SmtpClient($SmtpServer, 587)
$SMTPClient.EnableSsl = $true 
$SMTPClient.Credentials = New-Object System.Net.NetworkCredential("username", "password");
$SMTPClient.Send($SMTPMessage)
```

Comment: This might be duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20706869/powershell-is-missing-the-terminator)  since in line with `Attaching File` you seem to have different quotes. Other possibility is, that for example password contains double quotes. They would need to be escaped using `

Comment: Unlike almost every other Language, Powershell is fine with Smart quotes `“ ”`. Personally I don't use them but that's habit from the days before PS.

Comment: The script you've posted does not explain your symptoms. As an aside: better to avoid method syntax when calling cmdlets; e.g., instead of `New-Object System.Net.NetworkCredential("username", "password")` call `New-Object System.Net.NetworkCredential -ArgumentList "username", "password"`.

Comment: Script file should contain BOM for UTF8 to be properly recognized.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Block of code prevents script from running, but runs interactively](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37219078/block-of-code-prevents-script-from-running-but-runs-interactively)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fact that **[James C.'s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47247964/45375) was accepted by the OP** suggests that it was motivated by the OP's gratitude for the generally helpful, but non-specific - and ultimately potentially confusing - pointers contained in it.

Unfortunately, **it falls short as an answer of *general interest* to future readers and is *likely to cause confusion***; as of this writing:

- It contains an overtly incorrect claim:

> The issue here is that the $file is outside the param for the message, moving the quote will fix that: `Write-Host “Attaching File :- $file”`

However, there is *no* problem with `Write-Host “Attaching File :- ” $file`, because Write-Host simply concatenates multiple arguments with spaces - no strict need for a *single* argument.
(As stated, PowerShell recognizes "smart quotes" (non-ASCII quotes), *assuming they're properly encoded* - see below).

- It does *not* explain the OP's symptoms as posted.
- It almost makes it sound as if it weren't possible to embed a literal `"` - or `$`, for that matter - in a double-quoted string due to a limitation in PowerShell, which, of course, isn't true; escaping with backticks is all that is needed: `` "Pa`$`$`"w0rd" ``.

---

Instead, [PetSerAl](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4003407/petseral)'s helpful comments on the question *presumably* point to the actual answer:

- **There may be a *character encoding* issue**, given that "smart quotes" (non-ASCII quote characters) are used, which would surface in an incorrectly encoded *script file*.
- PetSerAl's [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37235562/45375) suggests that UTF-8-encoded script content must be saved to a file *with a BOM* in order for PowerShell to recognize the encoding.
- *Update*: PetSerAl surmises that the "actual troublemaker is an EN DASH here:
  `–ArgumentList`, which, when improperly decoded: `[Text.Encoding]::GetEncoding(1250).GetString([Text.Encoding]‌​::UTF8.GetBytes('–')‌​)`, yields `â€“`, an unpaired double quote."

Comment: Thanks for all the info guys. I found the issue. It was something with my password that was causing the issue. I changed it and now it works, cant believe I missed that. Also All this caused me to look into another question I had and found the answer. FYI: For multi line of body, $mail.BodyFormat = MailFormat.Html            Then $Body = @" and end with "@

Answer (score 1):

> At F:\email.ps1:9 char:1 + { + ~ Missing closing '}' in statement block or type definition.

The issue here is that the `$file` is outside the param for the message, moving the quote will fix that:

```
Write-Host “Attaching File :- $file”
```

(Smart Quotes `“ ”` are accepted by PowerShell but aren't but most other languages, I personally avoid them to be sure.)

---

> At F:\email.ps1:16 char:126 + ... ential("username", "password"); + ~~~ The string is missing the terminator: ".

The double quotes you're using here: `("username", "password")` can cause Powershell to incorrectly interpret where the password ends if it contains certain special characters.

For example the password `Pa$$"w0rd` will cause issues when used in your script because of the double quote within.

It will be interpreted as `"Pa$$"` with the remaining `w0rd"` remaining ( which only contains a single quoteation mark and is not correctly terminated as a string)

To avoid this you can use single quotes instead, they are not evaluated and are interpreted as literals:

```
$SMTPClient.Credentials = New-Object System.Net.NetworkCredential('username', 'password')
```

See about [about_quoting_rules](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_quoting_rules?view=powershell-5.1) for more info on single and double quotes.